# Is (A->B<-C) a multi-step reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I want to know if:

```
A -> B <- C
```

a multi-step reaction OR are multiple reactions:

```
A -> B, C -> B
```

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

A reaction is generally something along the lines of
$$\ce{A->Z}$$
where A is your starting material and Z the product.

This reaction can also proceed stepwise, here shown via an intermediate Y:
$$\ce{A->Y->Z}$$

You could also add intermediate "steps" in the reaction, where you introduce more reactants (here B) to give the product:
$$\ce{A->Y ->[\ce{B}] Z}$$

One commonality that all these reactions share is that the arrow is always pointing one way (and usually to the right). This allows us to reorder your reaction as follows:
$$\ce{A->B<-C} \begin{cases} \ce{A->B}\\ \ce{C->B} \end{cases} $$

You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: +1: Thanks. This means that for a valid single-step and multi-step reaction, (TotalIntermediates = TotalSteps - 1) will hold true.

Comment: @A9S6 No, not really. It depends on the type of reaction (uni-, bi- or trimolecular). Only then do you know how many intermediate species you have.